# Problema con ventana de alerta en javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, error404, alert

El objetivo de mi código es que aparezca una alerta cada vez que el usuario haga click en alguna alternativa, sin embargo esa parte no funciona. Agradecería si alguien me pudiese ayudar. Probablemente estoy cometiendo varios errores al mismo tiempo, pues esta es mi primera vez programando en Javascript.

El código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TRIVIA CULTURAL</title>
</head>
<script>
  function inicio (){
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    // obtenemos los elementos con name = "diseñador"
    var elementos = document.getElementsByName("diseñador");
 
    // buscamos el seleccionado y lo mostramos por pantalla
    for (i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
        if (elementos[i].checked) {
            alert("Has seleccionado: "+ elementos[i].value);
        }
    }
}, false);
  }
  inicio();
</script>

<body onload ="inicio"()>
<div>
  <form action="../../form-result.php" method="post" target="_blank">
    <center>
    <h1>
    ¿Quién diseñó la cúpula de la catedral de Florencia?:
    </h1>
    <p><br>
    <input type="radio" name="diseñador" value=""> Leonardo Da Vinci<br>
    <input type="radio" name="diseñador" value=""> Filippo Brunelleschi<br>
    <input type="radio" name="diseñador" value="">Leon Battista Alberti<br>
    <input type="radio" name="diseñador" value="">Miguel Angel Buonarroti
    </p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Responder y ver resultados"></p>
    </center>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, haz clic en [edit] y cambia el título de tu pregunta por algo más descriptivo y que resuma el problema. Tal como está escrito parece un [*clickbait*](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickbait).

Comment: En la etiqueta body los parentesis están fuera de las comillas

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    function inicio (){
        window.addEventListener('change', function () {
        // obtenemos los elementos con name = "diseñador"
        var elementos = document.getElementsByName("diseñador");

        // buscamos el seleccionado y lo mostramos por pantalla
        for (i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
            if (elementos[i].checked) {
                alert("Has seleccionado: "+ elementos[i].value);
            }
        }
        }, false);
    }
inicio();
</script>
```

El error esta en la línea del window.addEventListener, tienes dentro del paréntesis 'load' y lo que debe detectar en realidad es un 'change', que es el cambio de estado del check.